# Kotlin Multiplatform - JS target data storage

Tags: database, web, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm currently exploring the idea of reusing some client side code via Kotlin Multiplatform.
The initial requirements were to share code between Android and iOS, so I set up a Lot client plus SQL Delight for data storage on the client.
Suddenly, a web client was requested, so I was wandering how to tackle the data storage when targeting Kotlin/JS. SQL Delight does not support it, although there is a JS driver implemented and a sample app using it.
So, it looks like the best choice is to use some NPM dependency. Can you recommend one that:

1. Is a relational DB, since using NoSql on the web while using RDBMS on the mobile clients might cause data model issues
2. Can store sensitive data in a safe way (full or partial encryption, etc)

Thanks!

Comment: Did you manage to get web added to a kotlin / gradle kmm project at all? If so, how? O:)